# How can i change color of one word in a dynamic textField in AS 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic-text

I have this function:

```
private function boldVerb(_phrase:String, _verb:String):String
{
    var newHtmlText:String = "";

    var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp([_verb]);

    newHtmlText = _phrase.replace(pattern, "<b>" + _verb + "</b>");
    return newHtmlText;
}
```

And I want to change the color of this "verb" that the function receives. Is it possible in AS3?

Comment: Did you ever try `<font color="#COLOR"></font>` tags instead of "b" tag in this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can either use a stylesheet or you use the `font` tag (assuming it's an html textfield).

```
<font color='#FF0000'>This is red</font>
```

See [documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText).

Comment: OMG! How can i forget this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, as this is the HTML formatted text you could have a stylesheet with .verb class and then tag span with class attribute verb will paint it however you want - this is for greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function boldVerb(_phrase:String, _verb:String):String
{
    var newHtmlText:String = "";

    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    format.color = 0x990000;

    var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp([_verb]);

    newHtmlText = _phrase.replace(pattern, "<b>" + _verb + "</b>");
    textField.setTextFormat(format);

    return newHtmlText;
}
```

If textField is a text field on the stage this should work, but this is how you do text formatting in AS3, do a google search on "AS3 TextFormat" for more info. First, create a new TextFormat object, and give it a property, I chose a dark red #990000 (0x990000 in AS) and then applied it to the text field. I am sure you're wanting to format the string itself, which I don't recall if that's possible in Flash, but you can certainly edit the text field itself. So you may have to string together some text fields to get a string of text with one accented word. hopefully that gets you a step closer! Good luck!